# Upload file to server and return name of file

Tags: php, html, file, server

I'm trying to upload a file to my php server, then return the name of the file to display in the html document. But I get the following

```
`error: Objektet wasn't found! The requested address was not found on this server. The link on the previous page appears to be incorrect or out of date Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.8`
```

My html Doc

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="server.php">
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" size="35">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
    </body>
</html>
```

My php doc

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
    if(isset($_POST["fileToUpload"])){
        $file = $_FILES["fileToUpload"];
        echo("File: ".$file);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors in PHP

```
<?php
 if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])){
        $file = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
        echo "File: ".$file;
    }
?>
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="server.php">
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" size="35">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
    </body>
</html>
```

Errors

1.`if(isset($_POST["file"])){` its not post it should be `$_FILES["fileToUpload"])` since its a file upload

2. `$file = $_FILES["file"];` and in your html you have defined file name as `fileToUpload` but your accessign unknown name so it should be `$file = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];`

Comment: Ye sorry about that, im gonna update answer, i just changed the name. still doesnt solve my problem

Comment: @Amar.please copy paste my code .i have tested it works fine

Comment: Youre right, it works. Sorry for my ignorance. I will put ur answer as solution as soon as i can

Comment: Could I ask you, whats the command to resend an image to display?

Comment: if you want to show uploaded image .in php code you have use move method to uplaod to particular folder and html for img src you have to specify the folder path and image name

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script you are asking for a form name that does not exist. In your form, the variable is called `fileToUpload` but in your script you are checking for `$_POST['file']`.

Also, the global $_FILES is an array with information about the file, so you cannot use `echo` to show its content. Use `echo $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']` since `$_FILES['formFieldName']['name']` will display the original name of the file on the client machine.